# Determine what devices are plugged in and their type

Tags: c++, winapi, port

I am attempting to list all devices currently plugged into the computer/laptop using Win32 API. When I say devices I mean; headphones, usb storage devices, HDMI connections(a TV or projector), a printer and etc.

**Whats the best Native Win32 function to use to simply detect what devices are plugged in and what type they are?**

Would the functions:

```
SetupDiClassGuidsFromNameA("Ports", 0, 0, &RequiredSize);
SetupDiClassGuidsFromNameA("Ports", (_GUID*)buf, RequiredSize*sizeof(GUID), &RequiredSize);
```

and

```
SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(DeviceInfoSet,numDev,&DeviceInfoData);
```

be best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Setup API is the way to go to enumerate devices in C++.

Here's a simple sample: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6445/Enumerate-Installed-Devices-Using-Setup-API